# PHP die function

Tags: php, html, echo, die

How could i use a php die function to only stop certain divs from loading? I understand it probably wouldnt be the exact same as die, but how could i stop only specific divs from loading? So i want the learn "col" and "col last" not to load, but for the div id bar to load. Also, how to i make it so the H2 tag in the if statement does not apply to the table in the else statement?

```
<html>
<body>



<div id="header">
<div id="site">
    <h1><a href="#">site</a></h1>
    </div>

   <div id="menuholder">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="about.php">about application</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


</div>

<div id="teaser">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div class="box">

<?php
session_start ();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
echo "<h2>Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!</h2>";
else
die("You must be logged in to view this page. 
Register to gain access to learn more about the application.    
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
<table>
<tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type='text' name='username'/></td><td>Password: </td> <td>              <input type='password' name='password'/></td> <td><input type='submit'  name='submit' value='Login'/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
");

?>


            <p>Information about the application would go here</p>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="bar">
    <div class="wrap">

    </div>
</div>



<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Learn <span class="red">More</span></h3>
        <p>More info </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>User <span class="red">Statistics</span></h3>
        <p>More info</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col last">
        <h3>About <span class="red">Phapsy</span></h3>
        <p>More info</p>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p class="right">Contact: </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `die()` indicates to PHP to stop processing any further.

This, however, would work:

```
<?php
session_start ();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "<h2>Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!</h2>";
    $auth = true;
} else {
    $auth = false; // Show the following HTML
?>
You must be logged in to view this page. 
Register to gain access to learn more about the application.    
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
<table>
<tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type='text' name='username'/></td><td>Password: </td> <td>              <input type='password' name='password'/></td> <td><input type='submit'  name='submit' value='Login'/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php } // End ?>
```

And then elsewhere...

```
<?php if ( $auth == true ) { // Display this HTML only if authenticated ?>
    <div class="col last">
        <h3>About <span class="red">Phapsy</span></h3>
        <p>More info</p>

    </div>
<?php } // End ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` part just display whatever text you want to display using `echo()` and `exit`. You don't need to `die()`.

Comment: oops... didnt ever think of that... haha

Answer (score 0):

Use an if block:

```
<?php if($stuff): ?>
    <div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

"die" is a full stop; there are ways to intercept it, but not convenient ways.  In a slightly different situation, "return" might do what you need (since it exits only the current function or file).

Answer (score 0):

"So i want the learn "col" and "col last" not to load". Highlight those lines with your mouse. Hit the delete key :)

If you don't want them to display, use an `if else` statement. It will look at the `if` part first, if it's true, it's executes the code, if it's false, it will move to the `else` statement and try that.

Comment: At least you can take a joke! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't die! Don't abandon hope -- there's always an alternative.

Try outputting your markup from within conditional statements.